# Is there any difference between Cleanse and a Mecurial Scimitar?

Tags: league-of-legends

Besides the 3 second CC reduction on Cleanse is there more differences? Does one get rid of certain debuffs that the other does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercurial (as well as QSS) removes Suppression but Cleanse do not.

You can see this on the table provided by [wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crowd_Control)

Otherwise it's the same.

Comment: I forgot about Crucible, wonder why that doesn't have the same effect as QSS though.

Comment: QSS is supposed to be the only counter to Suppress.  It's the "ultimate" CC-removal.

Comment: are you sure about removal of ignite?

Comment: @Vogel612 Yes, I've seen it done and tested that it works

Comment: Mecurial Scimitar is also able to remove effects like Morderkaiser's ultimate, Trundle's ultimate, while Cleanse is not.

Comment: Wow, thats really helpful. Does mercurial also remove things like liandry's and red buff? I'd assume so if it removes ignite and DoT ults, but it'd be nice to know. Also, where does olaf's ult fit into these? I'd like a table with his ult included haha.